# React Native cannot find variable $refresh req$

Tags: react-redux, react-native

[image: ct]

React Native cannot find variable $refresh req$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package.JSon  :-

"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",

Downgrade version 
 "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",

and Delete your package-lock file and delete npm module folder

and after that

1). npm install

2). react-native link

3). react-native run-android  // react-native run-ios

to Solve your issue

Happy Codding **Cheers!**

[image]